# Implement an efficient stack without pointers?

Tags: algorithm, pointers, data-structures, stack

So, I'm working in an environment where pointers are non-existent (or at least, inaccessible), and I'm trying to efficiently implement a stack. I have a stack implementation working, but it's O(n), which of course isn't as efficient as the usual O(1) you get with pointer-based stacks. I just can't figure out a better way to implement this.

Some important background of the limitations of this environment: there's a global array of instances of a class called Entity; variables can only store signed integers; and there's no method of using pointers or even creating new arrays. Super limited.

Entities have members for (x,y,z) coordinates, a map of strings to integers for arbitrary data storage (of integers, at least), and a list of strings for arbitrary string storage. The environment provides no way of comparing two strings, except by comparing them to hard-coded values, and it provides no native way of comparing two integers, unless one is hard-coded; so to compare two variable integers, you have to subtract them and compare to 0 (very Assembly-like in that regard).

The implementation I have now adds a new Entity instance to the list for each entry in the stack, storing its value and index in its map with the keys Value and Index (I know, original). Whenever a value is pushed onto the stack, I iterate through the list and increment the Index of each existing Entity, then create a new Entity with an Index of 0. When it's popped, I iterate through the list, find the one with Index=0, and copy that value; I decrement the Index of every non-zero Entity I find on that list.

It works perfectly, but of course that's O(n) for both pushing and popping. Even if I were to track the head Index somewhere, the only way to find the entry with the matching Index would be to subtract the head Index from all the entries first, which is still O(n).

Is there any way to do this more efficiently than O(n) without access to pointers or even additional arrays? Or is this the best that can be done with these restrictions?

Comment: What language are you using? Why are pointers unavailable?

Comment: @Dai It's a scripting language for a video game; it's not meant to be a full-fledged programming language, which is why it's so limited, but I always enjoy pushing the boundaries on what can be done, hence why I'm trying to make this work, if at all possible.

Comment: If you make the top of the stack at the end rather than the beginning, you wouldn't need to change the indices of any elements whenever you do a push or pop, thus those can both be done in O(1). Although the exact limitations you're working with is somewhat underspecified.

Comment: @Dukeling The indices wouldn't need to change, but without pointers, how can I find the "end of the stack"? I'd have to iterate through all stack elements to find the one with the highest index, making it O(n) again, right? Or is there another way of finding it without pointers that I'm missing?

Comment: Can't you store a variable (e.g. indicating the size of the stack) which would allow you to look up the last element in the map in O(1)? I can't really give more specific advice (or know whether that would work) without knowing the exact details of what methods you have available to you. Note that RAM is basically just an array and pointers are basically just indices in this array, so if you only have a big array, you can probably implement something similar to RAM to have pointers.

Comment: Yes, I can store the stack size, but then how do I look up the entry given that index? I have no control over where in memory the entries are stored, and as I said, I can't get a pointer to the entries or create my own arrays, so the only way to relate that index back to the entry itself would be to search through all the entries and find the one with the proper index, yes? *EDIT* To be clear, while there is a global array of Entities that I can iterate through, I can't actually access that array by index, only by iteration.

Comment: What about using map within single entity as a stack? If you can introduce int->string conversion (any conversion, which gives unique string from given number is OK, you don't have to get proper representation of that number), then store "stack" size in variable. E.g. push: increase stack size, store data in map with key obtained from converting stack size to string. Pop: get value by key from stack size, decrease stack size. Map is normally O(log n) for lookup/insert, which looks better.

Comment: Also it's really hard to give any advices without tool knowledge. Can you name your scripting language? Is it open to public?